# Mongo Aggregation

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb

I have following documents in my collection

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("54490b8104f7142f22ecc97f"),
        "title": "Sample1",
        "slug": "samplenews",
        "cat": "sports",
        "desc": "sampletextsampletext",
        "published_date": ISODate("2014-10-23T14:06:57.0Z"),

} {
    "_id": ObjectId("54490b8104f7142f22ecc97f"),
        "title": "Sample2",
        "slug": "samplenews2",
        "category": "entertaintment",
        "desc": "sampletextsampletext",
        "published_date": ISODate("2014-10-22T14:06:57.0Z"),

} {
    "_id": ObjectId("54490b8104f7142f22ecc97f"),
        "title": "Sample3",
        "slug": "samplenews3",
        "category": "entertaintment",
        "desc": "sampletextsampletext",
        "published_date": ISODate("2014-9-22T14:06:57.0Z"),

} {
    "_id": ObjectId("54490b8104f7142f22ecc97f"),
        "title": "Sample4",
        "slug": "samplenews4",
        "category": "other",
        "desc": "sampletextsampletext",
        "published_date": ISODate("2014-10-22T14:06:57.0Z"),

}
```

I need one query to  get top 5 latest news from each category.any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the latest version of mongodb installed, one way of doing it is:

- `Sort` the records based on the `published_date` in descending order.
- `group` the records based on their `category`. For each group, collect all the records together in an array.
- In the javascript/client side code, `slice` the top 5 records, of each group(category).

The `$slice` is not available in the server side `$project` aggregation pipeline operator, which holds us from performing the operation on the server side.

```
var result = db.collection.aggregate(
[
{$sort:{"published_date":-1}},
{$group:{"_id":"$category","values":{$push:"$$ROOT"}}}
]
).map(function(doc){
return {"category":doc._id,"records":doc.values.slice(0,5)};
});
```

The `result` variable will now be an array of documents. Each document representing each `category` and in turn having an array of top `5` records.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort and then limit your request.

```
$top_five_other = iterator_to_array($db->find(array('category'=>'other')->sort(array('published_date'=>-1))->limit(5));
```

Comment: so do I have to write 5 queries if I'm having 5 categories?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. There may be a way to throw them all into one query, so you could check the advanced query documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try aggregate query

1-db.collection.aggregate({ $group : { _id : { category:"$category"}, total : { $sum : 1 }}},{$sort:{_id:1}})

OR

db.collection.aggregate({ $group : { _id : { category:"$category"}, total : { $sum : 1 }}},{$sort:{_id:1}})..forEach( function(myDoc) { 
                    print(myDoc._id.category);

})